# android currency code is not proper due to Locale

Tags: android, locale, currency

My app has a language changing option in spinner, the languages used are as follows
1. English
2. Italy
3. Simplified Chinese 
4. Traditional Chinese

I have loaded all language strings in the corresponding values folder. But, when i tried to load traditional chinese, i am able to get text of Simplified Chinese only.

After searching in google about this, i tried loading the language based on Locale.

Following is my code of Spinner selection and action

```
        langSpinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.lanuage_spinner1);
        langSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) 
            {   
                if (pos == 0) 
                {
                    langSelected ="en";
                    locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                }
                else if (pos == 1) 
                {
                    langSelected ="it";
                    locale = Locale.ITALIAN;
                } 
                else if (pos == 2) 
                {
                    langSelected ="zh";
                    locale = Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE;
                }               
                else if (pos == 3)
                {
                    langSelected ="zh-rTW";
                    locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE;
                }

                changeLang(langSelected, pos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }   
        });


public void changeLang(String lang, int pos)
    {
        if (lang.length() != 0)
        {
            //locale = new Locale(lang);            
            android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


       // here using intent call the same activity again

        }
    }
```

Now my problem is in the next activity i use to show a currency value "$", from my back end server i use to get currency code as USD and by parsing it in following code i use to show "$"

```
public static Currency parseCurrencyCode(String currencyCode) {
        if (currencyCode.equals("RMB")) {
            return Currency.getInstance("CNY");
        }
        try {
            return Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unknown Currency " + currencyCode);
        }
    }
```

After adding the above said Locale for loading Traditional Chinese Strings i am not getting the "$" value.

```
If selected language is English, currency will be as USD
If selected language is Italy, currency will be as USD
If selected language is Simplified Chinese, currency will be as US$
If selected language is Traditional Chinese, currency will be as $
```

Why this happens ?

I have gone through [this](http://speakman.net.nz/blog/2013/10/21/android-currency-localisation-hell/), saying that due to locale some currency use to appear as explained above. How to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following method i am able to get the currency codes

```
String currencyCode = "USD";
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(digits);        
String symbol = currency.getSymbol(Locale.US);

DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = ((java.text.DecimalFormat) format).getDecimalFormatSymbols();
decimalFormatSymbols.setCurrencySymbol(symbol);
((java.text.DecimalFormat) format).setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);

return format.format(value);
```